# Python regular expression find and output a part of the pattern in multiple times

Tags: python, regex

Assume I have a string as follows:

```
2021/12/23 13:00 14:00 2021/12/24 13:00 14:00 15:00
```

Where a `date` comes with `time` several times. Is it possible that regular expression can find all time after each `date` such as follows?

```
[('2021/12/23', '13:00','14:00'), ('2021/12/24', '13:00','14:00','15:00')]
```

I tried the following code in Python, but it returns only the first time:

```
re.findall(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)(\s\d+\:\d+)+','2021/12/23 13:00 14:00 2021/12/24 13:00 14:00 15:00')

>>>[('2021/12/23', ' 14:00'), ('2021/12/24', ' 15:00')]
```

Appendix:
The original problem is in fact a more complicated case, where there are several texts between time, and it is difficult to replace them to '' directly:

```
2021/12/31 14:00 start 15:00 end 17:00 pending 18:00 ok 2021/12/31 14:00 begin 15:00 end  17:00 start 18:00 suspend
```

So the robust method here should be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70694621/6048186).

```
pattern = regex.compile(r'(?P<date>\d{4}/\d+/\d+)(?:\s?(?P<time>(\d+:\d+))\s+([^\d]+))+')
for m in pattern.finditer('2021/12/31 14:00 start 15:00 end 17:00 pending 18:00 ok 2021/12/30 14:00 begin 15:00 end  17:00 ggh 18:00 suspend'):
    print(m.capturesdict())
>>> {'date': ['2021/12/31'], 'time': ['14:00', '15:00', '17:00', '18:00']}
{'date': ['2021/12/30'], 'time': ['14:00', '15:00', '17:00', '18:00']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PyPi regex library to get the following to work:

```py
import regex
pattern = regex.compile(r'(?P<date>\d+/\d+/\d+)(?:\s+(?P<time>\d+:\d+))+')
for m in pattern.finditer('2021/12/23 13:00 14:00 2021/12/24 13:00 14:00 15:00'):
    print(m.capturesdict())
```

Output:

```
{'date': ['2021/12/23'], 'time': ['13:00', '14:00']}
{'date': ['2021/12/24'], 'time': ['13:00', '14:00', '15:00']}
```

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##ZU3LDoIwELz3KzbxsG0gQAEvjY9f8C4eCBRtYktT10S/HgGNwbjJzu7OTGb9ky69K4bBWN8HgqDP@sF8TaSDg@37TpreenPVPCDfHzZtTXpXtVH6acH3qrpFk0TGzlKlJl5EKFjXB7BgHHxCk8641owbxzzLZSrzNC9AFirLQJYTfunyh5brEVEoBmP5YBxxmzS1p3vQt9Y0xIVgbHVc5mIMOGdgjHMKihgWhvLfMM73oxMbhhc).

Since PyPi regex library does not "forget" all captures inside a group, and provided the groups are named, the `match.capturesdict()` returns the dictionary of all groups with their captures.

Comment: FYI: one can install [PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module by running `pip install regex` (or `pip3 install regex` depending on environment) in the terminal/console window.

Answer (score 2):

Use `re.findall`:

```py
inp = '2021/12/23 13:00 14:00 2021/12/24 13:00 14:00 15:00'
matches = re.findall(r'\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}(?: \d{1,2}:\d{2})*', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['2021/12/23 13:00 14:00', '2021/12/24 13:00 14:00 15:00']
```

Explanation of regex:

```regex
\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}    match a date in YYYY/MM/DD format
(?: \d{1,2}:\d{2})*  match a space followed by hh:mm time, 0 or more times
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `findall + split` solution:

```sh
import re

s = '2021/12/23 13:00 14:00 2021/12/24 13:00 14:00 15:00'

for i in re.findall(r'\d+/\d+/\d+(?:\s\d+\:\d+)+', s): print (i.split())
```

**Output:**

```
['2021/12/23', '13:00', '14:00']
['2021/12/24', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00']
```

[**Code Demo**](https://ideone.com/OZFg8V)

`\d+/\d+/\d+(?:\s\d+\:\d+)+` matches a date string followed by 1 or more time strings.

You. could also use:

```
print ([i.split() for i in re.findall(r'\d+/\d+/\d+(?:\s\d+\:\d+)+', s)])
```

To get output:

```
[['2021/12/23', '13:00', '14:00'], ['2021/12/24', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00']]
```

Comment: Sorry, the case is just an example, it will be much more complex than using split.

Comment: Provide details or more examples in question. An answer is based on the question asked.